# MacBook Pro on company network loses Internet access after 10 minutes, but still has internal network access

Tags: network, dns, internet

I have a Mac user that after 10 minutes loses Internet access.  The issue started yesterday.  I have recreated the location with the DNS addresses in my troubleshooting efforts.  When I restart after losing Internet access, everything is fine for about 10 minutes, then only the network drives are accessible, no Internet, and Office 365 Outlook doesn't connect to the Exchange server.  Wifi shows connected when I connect, but doesn't have Internet access either.  Any help resolving this is appreciated.

Comment: I just discovered WeKnow.ac malware on the Mac.  Attempting to clean that up now.

Comment: All malware removed and Mac is functioning successfully.